# Can a pfx file contain certificates not belonging to leaf certificate path?

Tags: ssl, certificate, pfx

PFX contains the below categories of certificate which are part of the leaf certificate chain.

- Issued Public Certificate (Client/Server)
- Intermediate CA Certificate
- Root CA certificate
- Private Key

**Can it have certificates that are not part of the chain?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's nothing inherent in the PFX/PKCS#12 structure which requires any certificates be related to any other certificates.

.NET Core has explicit tests to ensure that it can create "non-chain" PFXes and read them back:

- [ExportUnrelatedPfx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/50218eaa16dbe5812752919f2e195893cedea507/src/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/tests/CollectionTests.cs#L737-L782): Three EE/leaf certificates, no private keys.  Write, read back.
- [ExportMultiplePrivateKeys](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/50218eaa16dbe5812752919f2e195893cedea507/src/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates/tests/CollectionTests.cs#L803-L843): Two EE/leaf certificates, each with private keys. Write, read back.

The PFX is just:

- Some number of encrypted certificates
- Some number of encrypted private keys
- Some number of unencrypted certificates
- Some number of unencrypted private keys

(Usually there aren't any unencrypted ones, but the spec allows it.)

Each of the certificates and private keys has a tag to help mate them back together, to reduce the combinatoric logic of public/private key matching.